# What is the proper way to handle a ProgressDialog using Activity lifecycle methods?

Tags: android

I have been bitten by: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager", when using a ProgressDialog in an Activity.

**What is the proper way to handle a ProgressDialog using Activity lifecycle methods ?**

Working code example much appreciated...